# How to obtain the centroidal momentum matrix in Drake?

Tags: drake

When implementing the whole body controller using drake, I want to add the task of centroidal momentum regulation as shown below.

[image]

How can I obtain the centroidal momentum matrix and the bias acceleration term in Drake?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [CalcSpatialMomentumInWorldAboutPoint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a8979cb69b0e716ea4bd3ab21198996fb).

We also have [CentroidalMomentumConstraint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_centroidal_momentum_constraint.html); it's implementation might be helpful for you.

Searching in doxygen is lousy, but these turn up readily with a google search for "centroidal momentum site:drake.mit.edu"